# How retrieve the claim value inside a Razor page

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core

I have set some values with claims when the system logging.

```
public async Task<IActionResult> Login(string txtUserName, string txtPassword)
{
   string username = txtUserName;
   var claims = new List<Claim>
   {
     new Claim("username",username)
   };
}
```

Now I wants to access the claim values in the Razor page. I try to access with flowing code line that `@((ClaimsIdentity) User.Identity).GetSpecificClaim("username")` in my Razor page but it's not works.

```
<div class="container-nav">
    <a class="navbar-brand"><p>Website name</p></a>
    <div class="profile">
       <i class="fas fa-envelope"></i>
                   
       <a class="navbar-brand"><p>@((ClaimsIdentity)User.Identity).GetSpecificClaim("username")</p></a>


    </div>

</div>
```

Comment: There seems no such build-in method called `GetSpecificClaim("xxx")`, did you customize any extension method?  Besides, how do you add the Claim to User? In your code, you just create the Claim and do not add it to anywhere.

Comment: I used claims in creation of authorization policies.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add claims to `HttpContext.User` in backend like below:

```
public async Task<IActionResult> Login(string txtUserName, string txtPassword)
{
    string username = txtUserName;
    var claims = new List<Claim>
    {
        new Claim("username",username)
    };
    var appIdentity = new ClaimsIdentity(claims);
    HttpContext.User.AddIdentity(appIdentity); 

    //....
}
```

Then get the claims in frontend like below:

```
@User.FindFirst("username").Value
```

Comment: It works nicely. Thank you very much @Rena. Thanks a lot.

Comment: You're welcome. :)